# page refresh only when new records are inserted in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

What i want to do is whenever, a row is inserted into the database table by another service, the page that is accessing the database should refresh automatically, instead of using timer calls to check, is there a way to do it.
i wanted to in 2 different databases i.e MS SQL Server 2000 and 2008.

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more context to get meaningful answers; what type of application is this? A web application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL 2005 and onwards you'd use SQL Server Query Notifications and the SqlDependency class in C#

There is [a tutorial here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555893) that you can follow for SQL2005 onwards.

ASP.Net has [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) which is slightly different and works for earlier versions of SQL as well as current versions (it uses polling in SQL2000 and service broker in SQL2005+), but is ASP.Net specific, so you may have difficulty using it in a non web application.

Comment: Yes, SqlCacheDependency does, but it just uses polling i.e. timer calls to check. (now edited)